# HTML.TextAreaFor data binding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.title, new { id = "title", @class = "double text white" })
```

the data is not binded in the controller. When I save a model the attribute title remains null.

Comment: Can you show us your controller code please?

Comment: What type of title do you have? String or Double? I can't think case where title can be double, but classname "double" suggest that it may double.

Comment: thank you the problem was solved! to be honest i can't remember the solution, because i have a also a dropdownlistfor mapped also with model.title and i forgot